# one end group with positve first Betti number$\beta^{(2)}_1(G)>0$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, geometric-group-theory

Could anyone give me an example of a countable finitely generated (f.g.) discrete group $G$ with one end but have non-trivial $H^1(G,\ell^2G)$?

To be precise, consider the following two cases.

(1) Find a countable discrete f.g. **non-amenable** group G with $H^1(G,\mathbb{Z}G)=0$, but $\beta^{(2)}_1(G)\neq 0$.

(2) Find a countable discrete f.g. **amenable** group G with $H^1(G,\mathbb{Z}G)=0$, but $H^1(G,\ell^2(G))\neq 0$.

Any remarks, hint, references are welcomed!!

Thanks in advance!

---

Remarks:

1, It is well-known that a f.g. infinite group $G$ has 1-end iff $H^1(G, \mathbb{Z}G)=0$.

2, When $G$ is infinite, $H^1(G, \mathbb{Z}G)\hookrightarrow H^1(G,\ell^2(G))$.

3, When $G$ is a non-amenable countable discrete group,  $\beta^{(2)}_1(G)\neq 0\Longleftrightarrow H^1(G,\ell^2(G))\neq 0$ by corollary 2.4 in [this paper](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~peters10/petersonthom.pdf). This is not true for amenable group, as can be seen for $G=\mathbb{Z}$.

4, I suspect for (1), we might take a torsion group with positive first Betti number, but I do not know why it has 1-end. Is it possible for a torsion free group to satisfies conditions in (1)?

5, For (2), it might be easy to find examples, but I do not know even for $G=\mathbb{Z}^2$, how to find $H^1(G,\ell^2(G))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(2) If $G$ is an {\em arbitrary} infinite amenable countable group, then $H^1(G,\ell^2(G))$ is nonzero (because it is not Hausdorff!: the subspace of coboundaries $B^1(G,\ell^2(G))$ is not closed in the space of cocycles $Z^1(G,\ell^2(G))$. Hence if $G$ is a non-virtually-cyclic amenable countable group, e.g. $\mathbf{Z}^2$, it answers (2).

(1) The surface groups $\Gamma_g$, $g\ge 2$, are examples.

Comment: Thanks, to see the surface groups have one end, if my understanding is right, just look at the Cayley group(some tiling of the plane); is there any way to see directly that the surface groups could not be of the form predicted by the Stalling theorem? Btw, how to see in (2), $B^1$ is not closed?...

Comment: If $G$ is the fundamental group of a compact manifold whose universal covering has 1 end, then $G$ has 1 end. Actually ends of manifolds were introduced before ends of groups! And the interior of any compact manifold with a single boundary component is 1-ended. Hence you don't need Stallings to see that $\Gamma_g$ is 1-ended! You can also see it (this is almost the same argument) using that the Cayley graph of $\Gamma_g$ is a tiling of the hyperbolic plane.

Comment: Thanks again! It is good to know that...